# How to get rid of baby snails?

Tags: soil, pests, pest-control, snails

This has now become a severe problem. Last year nearly all of the young plants that I had planted were  eaten away by them. I used to throw away the bigger snails, later killed them by hitting as I didn't know any other way to get rid of them.

In between the winter came and they were all gone. Now these days when I am digging the soil, I can see like thousands of the these baby snails within the soil everywhere. I can't imagine what it will be like this year.

Is there a problem with my soil ? We have clayey type of soil. How to get rid of these snails/baby snails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your soil, although the fact it has a high clay content means it may hang on to water for longer, which is not a bad thing for plants, but will make good conditions for  slugs and snails because they need moisture. Snails hibernate during winter, but when active, they lay eggs; each one can lay up to 80 eggs each time,and these hatch out into tiny snails which also will lay eggs eventually. I'm afraid its probably time to resort to chemicals to reduce the population if the baby snails are becoming active - in the UK,I would use slug pellets which are coloured blue and contain either metaldehyde or methiocarb. Both of these chemicals are toxic to snails,but also toxic  to bird and aquatic wild life; overuse or excessive application is a major problem,where people  put so many down the soil appears blue, but a light  sprinkle once or twice a year should reduce the snail and slug population without creating toxicity problems. There are more organic slug and snail treatments,but these are not usually as effective - it rather depends what treatments are available where you live as to the choices you have. Otherwise, an old remedy was to sink small containers filled with beer into the soil - slugs and snails like the beer,fall in when trying to drink it, and die, probably in a state of inebriation.

Other home control methods are listed here [Organic Slug & Snail Control](https://www.learningwithexperts.com/gardening/blog/organic-slugs-snails-control), but are not so effective as using slug pellets.

Answer (score 3):

I know that if you have planted either vegetables or flowers in a container and you don't want to have snails start eating your plants, you can obtain some copper tape that's literally made of copper (you can get it on Amazon or other retailers online). This should prevent any snail from finding its way to your plants.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work - see video on hackaday showing snails crossing happily.

Answer (score 2):

I use snail bait in a feeding station so the bait doesn’t get mouldy. Lasts for months. If placed in a shady place near moisture then dead snails can be found in this structure, proving it works.

Two pot trays - one small to hold bait  and one big as a roof.

Two half bricks.

Bait containing Fe.EDTA as active ingredient - to avoid off-target poisoning.

I have been experimenting with this for
a very long time.

[image]

Placed near valuable seedlings, and then more structures placed along neighbor's fences to catch immigrating snails.

Comment: Where did you get Fe.EDTA ? Does it have any measurements?

Comment: Snail pellets. The Fe.EDTA is the active ingredient. The trays, well, I will measure etc. tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, is this https://www.amazon.in/FeGro-Iron-EDTA-12-500/dp/B07JQTNDQB/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1Y6J55KLFUILP&dchild=1&keywords=fe+edta&qid=1613381301&sprefix=fe+edta%2Caps%2C452&sr=8-5 it? It says something 12%, I asked about that.

Comment: The rest of the snail bait is just wheat bran and colouring. Also, the active ingredient breaks down in sunlight so keep it in the shade.

Comment: If you make your own, let us know your recipe and how it works.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can do, Thanks.